# Get binary data from string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split, byte

After sending some information through a socket i have a binary object that looks like this:

```
b"1:b'5Q\x19aw\x17\x8c\x98\x10\x1c\xe0O\x14\xd1x\xa1'"
```

What I want to do is get the first part before the : as a string and the second as a binary. Like this:

```
'1'
```

and:

```
b'5Q\x19aw\x17\x8c\x98\x10\x1c\xe0O\x14\xd1x\xa1'
```

With all my attempts I ended up with either:

```
b"b'5Q\x19aw\x17\x8c\x98\x10\x1c\xe0O\x14\xd1x\xa1'"
```

or:

```
"b'5Q\x19aw\x17\x8c\x98\x10\x1c\xe0O\x14\xd1x\xa1'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split it on `b':'` and decode and trim accordingly:

```
i, j = r.split(b':')
i = i.decode()  #  '1'
j = j[2:-1]
```

Now:

```
print(i)
# 1
print(j)
# b'5Q\x19aw\x17\x8c\x98\x10\x1c\xe0O\x14\xd1x\xa1'
```

Comment: Thank you, so simple.
Actually instead of j = j[2:-1] i just used j.
Otherwise i get only part of the message.